# GWT twitter share button

Tags: java, twitter, gwt

I followed the twitter share API - normal text from here

https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button

Tried this

```
Button twitterButton = new Button();
twitterButton.setHTML("<a href=\"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+tab.getUrlHeader()+"  data-size=\"large\"> <img src=\"img/social/twitter.png\"  >   </a>");
```

But on button click nothing pops up or happens.

Do i need to add any click handler on button ..?

any help is appreciated ..

Comment: Does `tab.getUrlHeader()` return an HTML-escaped String? Because if it doesn't, you probably need to add a couple of single or double quotes in there, like this: `...tweet?text=\""+tab.getUrlHeader()+"\"  data-size...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a Button for this. But just a HTML element.

```
HTML twitterButton = new HTML();
twitterButton.setHTML("<a class=\"twitter-share-button\" href=\"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+tab.getUrlHeader()+"\" data-size=\"large\" target=\"_blank\"> <img src=\"img/social/tweet.jpg\"  >   </a>");
```

Note that I also find the actual html you are using a little bit strange ?
You are never using class="twitter-share-button" although on the link you provide the first thing they say is : Create a new anchor element with a twitter-share-button class...

Comment: well that was really help full , but there is one issue , i added the twitter script in my html file , but it is not working , do i need to create some different file with different name , and if so , where do i need to keep the script file ..?

Comment: I think your html is just wrong. But I never did create a twitter button...

<a href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @TwitterDev</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: hey , it worked , i came to know later on that becuase of some proxy issue , twitter was not opening , the same code snippet u shared worked , i juts added one more thing  in anchor tag - i added target="_blank " - so that twittter opens up in new tab

Comment: one more question if u can help , you know how can i add a pic in this tweet ...?

Comment: I don't understand your last question.

Comment: in the same tweeter share - how can i add image ..?

Comment: I still have no idea ? Screenshot of what you mean ?